# Add buttons to NavigationItem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I try to add button and ImageView on NavigationItem. For this objects I added two functions TouchUp for it. This two objects I added on uiview. UIView I added to UINavigaionItem. I added UIGesture for ImageView and TouchUp action for button.  But button and ImageView don't clicking.
The code bellow:

```
    let navView = UIView()
    navView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.on_clicked_btn(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(-65, -22, 130, 42)
    btn.setTitle("title", forState: .Normal)
    btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center
    btn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    btn.titleLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    photo.frame = CGRect(x: -110, y: -18, width: 33, height: 33)
    photo.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    photo.layer.masksToBounds = false
    photo.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
    photo.layer.cornerRadius = self.photo_avatar.frame.height/2
    photo.clipsToBounds = true

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.on_clicked_photo(_:)))
    photo.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    photo.userInteractionEnabled = true

    navView.addSubview(photo)
    navView.addSubview(btn)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navView
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is your swift version?

Comment: Swift version is 2.2

Comment: Is it an old project

Comment: try with `self.on_clicked_btn(_:)` instead of `ViewController.on_clicked_btn(_:)` and let me know

Comment: @ReinierMelian It will not work any how as he is not initialising navView rect. so buttons and photo are created outside navView bounds

Comment: The issue is the frame of the UIView you are right @RahulDasgupta

Comment: Yep! thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you were not initialising UIIview rect in:

```
let navView = UIView()
```

Replace this with

```
let navView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 168, height: 40))
```

Replace bin frame with:

```
btn.frame = CGRect(x: 38, y: 0, width: 130, height: 42)
```

and photo frame

```
photo.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 33, height: 33)
```